# R fast quantile calculation for confidence intervals

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate quantiles for every "slice" of a dataset, in order to get some kind of "confidence intervals" at a 99% level. I manage this with base R, but it is excruciatingly slow. Any idea to speed up, or for a better approach, is welcome.

```r
a <- (1:20000)/100
b <- 20001:40000

speedseq <- data.frame(a, b)
work_quantile <- rep(NA, nrow(speedseq))
    
myfunc <- function() {
  

  for(i in 1: nrow(speedseq)) {
    work_quantile[i] <- quantile(speedseq$b[speedseq$a>=(speedseq$a[i] - 1) & 
                                                       speedseq$a<=speedseq$a[i]], na.rm = T, probs = 0.99)
    if(i%%10000==0) print(round(i/nrow(speedseq),3))
  }
  mean(is.na(work_quantile))

}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfunc(), times = 1)
   Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 myfunc() 5.185645 5.185645 5.185645 5.185645 5.185645 5.185645     1
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about your slices, they are not always of equal length, right? They start 1, 1:2, 1:3, ... but at some point they start later than 1. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I just abitrarily chose to consider data where `a` is between `a[i]-1` and `a[i]`, so the first rows won't have many observations

Answer (score 2):

You could parallelize it.

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, 'speedseq')

r0 <- parSapply(cl, 1:nrow(speedseq), \(i) unname(quantile(speedseq$b[speedseq$a >= (speedseq$a[i] - 1) & 
                                                    speedseq$a <= speedseq$a[i]], na.rm=T, probs=0.99)))
stopifnot(all.equal(work_quantile, r0))

stopCluster(cl)
```

---

*Other approaches:*

If you want slices of 1, 1:2, 1:3, ... 1:nrow, you could do

```
r1 <- vapply(1:nrow(speedseq), \(x) quantile(speedseq$b[seq.int(1, x)], .99), numeric(1))
```

If you want 1:100, 2:101, 2:102, ..., (nrow - 99):nrow, you could do

```
r2 <- vapply(1:(nrow(speedseq) - 99), \(x) quantile(speedseq$b[seq.int(x, x + 99)], .99), numeric(1))
```

If you want just slices of 100 each you could do

```
r3 <- vapply(seq(1, nrow(speedseq), 100), \(x) quantile(speedseq$b[seq.int(x, x + 99)], .99), numeric(1))
```

Comment: does that bring any speedup on your side ? thing is, I'd like to keep the current slicing approach (adaptive slices)

Comment: @gaut Should do so, It avoids the a comparison.

Comment: ah yes but I'd like to keep it sorry

Comment: @gaut r2 should be similar. otherwise, perhaps try the `parallel` package

Comment: @gaut As said, try `parallel`izing it, see update.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `data.table` which uses the `data.table` non-equi join: (not sure how memory efficient it will be but it took 4 seconds to run locally)

For each row, pre-define the upper bound, lower bound and row id:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(speedseq)

speedseq[, upper_bound := a]
speedseq[, lower_bound := a - 1]
speedseq[, row_id := .I]
```

Do a non-equi on itself. Read as:

- In the first line, let's call the `speedseq` on the right `i`, and the `speedseq` on the left `X`
- This is your data.table merge syntax which means "for each row in `i`, find the rows that match from `X`
- The match condition is that `X.a >= i.lower_bound` and `X.a <= i.upper_bound`. Again, taking the `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` from one row of `i`, this is saying "give me all rows in X where `a` is between these bounds
- The `.(row_id = i.row_id, a = i.a, b)` specifies what I want to keep, meaning I want to keep the `row_id` and `a` from `i`, and the values of `b` that came from `X`
- Lastly, compute the required quantile by `row_id`

  ```
    speedseq[speedseq,
      .(row_id = i.row_id, a = i.a, b),
      # Non equi join
      on = .(a >= lower_bound,
             a <= upper_bound)
    ][, .(work_quantile = quantile(b, na.rm = T, probs = 0.99)), by = .(row_id)]
  ```